# Proper way to concatenate variable strings

Tags: ansible

I need to create new variable from contents of other variables. Currently I'm using something like this:

```
- command: echo "{{ var1 }}-{{ var2 }}-{{ var3 }}"
  register: newvar
```

The problem is:

- Usage of `{{ var1 }}...{{ varN }}` brings too long strings and very ugly code.
- Usage of `{{ newvar.stdout }}` a bit better but confusing.
- Usage of `set_fact` module caches *fact* between runs. It isn't appropriate for me.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Good question. But I think there is no good answer which fits your criteria. The best I can think of is to use an extra vars file.

A task like this:

```
- include_vars: concat.yml
```

And in `concat.yml` you have your definition:

```
newvar: "{{ var1 }}-{{ var2 }}-{{ var3 }}"
```

Answer (score 64):

Since strings are lists of characters in Python, we can concatenate strings the same way we concatenate lists (with the + sign):

```
{{ var1 + '-' + var2 + '-' + var3 }}
```

If you want to pipe the resulting string to some filter, make sure you enclose the bits in parentheses:

e.g. To concatenate our 3 vars, and get a sha512 hash:

```
{{ (var1 + var2 + var3) | hash('sha512') }}
```

Note: this works on Ansible 2.3.  I haven't tested it on earlier versions.

Comment: While correct, the much safer operator for concatenating strings in Jinja is actually [the tilde (`~`)](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#other-operators) operator.

Answer (score 29):

As simple as joining lists in python itself.

```
ansible -m debug -a msg="{{ '-'.join(('list', 'joined', 'together')) }}" localhost
```

---

```
localhost | SUCCESS => {
  "msg": "list-joined-together" }
```

---

Works the same way using variables:

```
ansible -m debug -a msg="{{ '-'.join((var1, var2, var3)) }}" localhost
```

Comment: Just an aside. Why does `ansible -m debug -a msg="title {{ '-'.join((var1, var2, var3)) }}" localhost` not work?

Comment: @orodbhen not 100% sure but it feels like some weird arg parsing issue - try: `ansible -m debug -a "msg='{{ var1 }} title {{ var1 }} {{ \"-\".join((var1, var2, var3)) }}'" localhost -e var1=test -e var2=foo -e var3=bar`

Comment: Interestingly enough, this _also_ works: `ansible -m debug -a "msg='{{ var1 }} title {{ var1 }} {{ '-'.join((var1, var2, var3)) }}'" localhost -e var1=test -e var2=foo -e var3=bar`