# Best practice to concatenate strings in Ansible variables: Using one Jinja2 expression or multiple?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to determined what is the better practice to concatenate strings, when working with Ansible variables.

Is it better to concat outside the Jinja2 expression, or within? When might someone prefer one over the other?

Here are a few examples of how I've seen both methods utilized.

```yaml
vars:

  prefix: var1
  suffix: var2

tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ prefix }}-suffix"
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ prefix }}-{{ suffix }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ prefix + '-suffix' }}"
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ prefix + '-' + suffix }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ prefix ~ '-suffix' }}"
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ prefix ~ '-' ~ suffix }}"
```

Comment: You may also have a look into [Proper way to concatenate variable strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46550570/6771046) and consider use cases where additional filter needs to be applied like in `{{ (var1 + var2 ) | lower }}`. An other approach might be to use `{{ '-'.join((var1, var2)) }}`. So the answer will depend on what you try to achieve.

Comment: @U880D  I think you just answered my question, you'd do the concat inside a jinja expression when you'd want to pass the result to a filter.  Make that an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is it better to concat outside the Jinja2 expression, or within? When might someone prefer one over the other?*

In Jinja2 it is safer to use the [tilde operator (`~`)](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#other-operators) for concatenating strings since it

> *Converts all operands into strings and concatenates them.*

Considering use cases where additional filter needs to be applied, concatenating inside a Jinja expression might be prefered. In example like

```yaml
{{ (prefix ~ '-' ~ suffix) | upper }}
{{ '-'.join((prefix, suffix)) | lower}}
```

**Credits To**

- [Proper way to concatenate variable strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46550570/6771046)